# Can i use events as an if statement condition

Tags: jquery

is it possible to use events as conditions ?
and what if i want to say do this when the event on table cell is onclick :

```
if($(this).bind(onclick)){}
```

is this correct ?

Comment: `.bind()` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery. As the names suggested, it gets you started.

Answer (score 2):

Events are triggered when something occurs. If you click on a table cell, then a `click` event is triggered. You can't use them as conditions in `if` statements, but if you want to do something when a certain event happens, that's what an event handler is for.

As an example, this would bind an event handler for the `click` event to all table cells (`<td>` elements) present when the code is executed (on DOM ready):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('table cell clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you it helps much. However ,i though of if statement because i wanted to loop on each table cell and check if it has been clicked

Comment: @user1978654 You'd have to use an event handler for the `click` event and mark the table cell as having been clicked on (you could use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function for that), then check for the presence of that when looping through the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal javascript, but not very useful. It will never do anything because the body of the if statement is empty. In addition, because `.bind()` returns the jQuery object, the condition will always be true. So although the javascript is legal and in that sense "correct", it is not very useful for anything.